# create dump file from database in mysql

Tags: mysql, dump

following is the that I create dump from mysql database.

```
mysqldump -u root tempbkk > ttt.dump
```

but I want to create a dump that exclude one or more file while creating dump from database we select.What is the command for that ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`mysqldump` can skip tables, you need the `--ignore-table` parameter. Check out the [manual of `mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 48):

`mysqldump -u user -p some_database > some_database_dump.sql`

Comment: I can't see that this answers the question.

Comment: should be `mysqldump -u user -p some_database > some_database_dump.sql`

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> --databases <dbname> -r <NameofBackup.sql>
```

Comment: Hi! Code only answers are considered low quality on SO; please consider adding an explanation to your code snippet as to improve it for OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway as far as I can see this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type this command `mysqldump -u user -p database_name_in_database > name_of_file.sql`

it will ask password for `user`. and there you go, your dumb file is ready. on same the location from where you run the command